# I have a little error in my snake game

Tags: java

I see this error sometimes (sometimes it appears and sometimes not) when i "hit" in yellow point ([image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7UWTn.png)) but i have no idea why..
I know maybe its look very chaotic but it's my first time when i a make game in java.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 22
at Gameplay.paint(Gameplay.java:140)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(JComponent.java:5210)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(RepaintManager.java:1579)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1502)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(RepaintManager.java:1272)
at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5158)
at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4969)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:831)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(RepaintManager.java:814)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:814)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:789)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:738)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(RepaintManager.java:64)
at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1732)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

And here is my paint method:

```
 if (enemyXPos[xPos] == snakeXLenght[0] && enemyYPos[yPos] == snakeYLenght[0]) {

        score++;
        lenghtOfSnake++;
        xPos = random.nextInt(34);
        yPos = random.nextInt(23);
    }

    //line140:
    enemyImage.paintIcon(this, graphics, enemyXPos[xPos], enemyYPos[yPos]);


    for (int b = 1; b < lenghtOfSnake; b++) {
        if (snakeXLenght[b] == snakeXLenght[0] && snakeYLenght[b] == snakeYLenght[0]) {
            right = false;
            left = false;
            up = false;
            down = false;

            graphics.setColor(Color.white);
            graphics.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 50));
            graphics.drawString("YOU LOSE", 300, 300);

            graphics.setFont(new Font("arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
            graphics.drawString("Space to  RESTART", 350, 340);
        }
    }

    graphics.dispose();
}
```

and here are my arrays:

```
private int[] enemyXPos = {25, 50,  75,  100, 125, 150, 175, 200, 225, 250, 275, 300, 325, 350, 375, 400, 425, 450, 475, 500, 525, 550, 575, 600, 625, 650, 675, 700, 725, 750, 775, 800, 825, 850};
private int[] enemyYPos = {75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200, 225, 250, 275, 300, 325, 350, 375, 400, 425, 450, 475, 500, 525, 575, 600, 625};
```

if i showed not enough code, just say and i paste more.

Comment: Which line is 140? Your problem is either the value of xPos, yPos,  or b.

Comment: "enemyImage.paintIcon(this, graphics, enemyXPos[xPos], enemyYPos[yPos]);" this is a line 140

Comment: Double check the arrays for enemy positioning.  My guess would be that `xPos = random.nextInt(34); yPos = random.nextInt(23);` one of these are greater than the size of the array.

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say this is a simple off by one error. I agree with @RJ7 , check your arrays.

Comment: Have you tried to understand what the exception means and how it can help you troubleshoot your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Gameplay.java`, on line `140` (in your `paint()` method), you are trying to get something out of an array. That array is smaller than the index you are giving it (you are trying to get item at index `22`, but the array might have `21` or fewer items).

Make sure `enemyXPos` and `enemyYPos` are both equal to or larger than `xPos` and `yPos`, respectively.

Comment: private int[] enemyXPos = {25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200, 225, 250, 275, 300, 325, 350, 375, 400, 425,
            450, 475, 500, 525, 550, 575, 600, 625, 650, 675, 700, 725, 750, 775, 800, 825, 850};

    private int[] enemyYPos = {75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200, 225, 250, 275, 300, 325, 350, 375, 400, 425,
            450, 475, 500, 525, 575, 600, 625};

Comment: @Pablito Please [edit]
  your question instead of posting your update in the comments

Comment: Sorry for that illegible post but you had right, my array "enemyYPos" have 22 elements and i wanted use 23 elements... :D but still i have no idea why only sometimes i had this error and not when i started the app

Comment: Glad I could help. Best of luck, @Pablito!

Comment: @Pablito, you only get this sometimes because the error depends on the value coming back from your `random.nextInt` call.

Answer (score -2):

This code is not enough to give a concrete answer, but it looks like your `enemyXPos` or `enemyYPos` sizes are not enough.

Comment: private int[] enemyXPos = {25, 50, 75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200, 225, 250, 275, 300, 325, 350, 375, 400, 425,
            450, 475, 500, 525, 550, 575, 600, 625, 650, 675, 700, 725, 750, 775, 800, 825, 850};



    private int[] enemyYPos = {75, 100, 125, 150, 175, 200, 225, 250, 275, 300, 325, 350, 375, 400, 425,
            450, 475, 500, 525, 575, 600, 625};

Comment: This should be a comment, for future reference. It is not a properly formatted answer.